# Using PropertyChanged from reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, propertychanged

I want to get a notification when object attribute is changed by using reflection.

This is one of class in mjpeg.dll:

```
public class MJPEGConfiguration : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string psw;
        public string   password
        {
            get
            {
                return psw;
            }
            set
            {
                psw = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PSW");
            }
        }

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my camera.cs, I set the MJPEGConfiguration object to "object Configuration" and add a PropertyChanged event to this object:

```
    public object Configuration
    {
        get 
        {
            return configuration; 
        }
        set
        {
            configuration = value;

            Type t = configuration.GetType(); //t is the type of "MJPEGConfiguration"
            EventInfo ei = t.GetEvent("PropertyChanged");
            MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("My_PropertyChanged");
            Delegate dg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, mi);
            ei.AddEventHandler(configuration, dg);
        }
    }

    public void My_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

However, I'm getting ArgumentException(Error binding to Target Method) in the line of "Delegate dg = ...."
How can I fix this problem? Or is there any correct way to do this?

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, feel free to mark it as accepted. If it wasn't, please add a comment as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of .CreateDelegate you are calling is trying to bind to a static method. For an instance method, do this:

```
Delegate dg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(et, value, mi);
```

Comment: PS - You might want to rethink using Object as the type for Configuration. I'd argue for using the concrete type or an interface. Using one of those allows you to get rid of the reflection code.